# Can someone tell me what navigatorkey does in flutter?

Tags: flutter

```dart
final navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

....
  static final Config config = Config(
    tenant: 'YOUR_TENANT_ID',
    clientId: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
    scope: 'openid profile offline_access',
    redirectUri: kIsWeb
        ? 'http://localhost:8483'
        : 'https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf',
    navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

The navigator key purpose is to identify and access the navigator from anywhere in your app. This way you can call method on the navigator like this :

```
navigatorKey.currentState?.pushNamed(routeName, arguments: arguments);
```

This can be useful when you need to navigate without a `BuildContext`